# Coinbase API Test Buy and Sell API

Tags: java, spring, rest, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I am working on a Spring 5 and Java 8 application that I want to make buys and sells for me on Coinbase using the Coinbase API.   I have followed the instructions to create an app in Coinbase, I have the keys, I am able to use Oauth2 to get Authorization, and I am able to get an access token.   I am now able to access the Coinbase API collection to create a BUY order or SELL order.

However, I personally have very, very little bitcoin, just for testing, and I wanted to be able to test the API call without having to make an actual buy or sell ... can I do this.   Is there an account I can use to do a mock buy or sell without actually doing an order?

If I can't, then testing is going to get messy.  I saw that Coinbase Pro API has a sandbox for Buy and Sell orders, but I don't know if it is still supported.  Do I have to use Coinbase Pro for a sandbox?

Any thoughts or help would be much appreciated!   Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like Sandbox is active and live from Feb 2015, hope it will work, you can check below link for more details about [Sandbox](https://developers.coinbase.com/blog/2015/02/20/sandbox).

Comment: The links in the article provided in the answer are no longer valid..